# How to reference objects by $(".className")?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get an array of objects belonging to a certain class on a webpage.

This is my very first experiment with JQuery and JS, so please be understanding.

I would like to return an array of all items belonging to the class `dataRow odd`.

Currently I am trying `$('.dataRow odd')` and `$('.dataRow.odd')` as seen [here.](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) and [here.](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/)

For some of the outer classes, this method seems to work, and I can get the element. As soon as I get into one that is further in (more indented), it won't.

This is the html of the table that I'm trying to access:

```
    <div class="listRelatedObject caseBlock">
<div class="bPageBlock brandSecondaryBrd secondaryPalette">
    <form action="/p/case/CaseMassAction?retURL=%2F500%3Fisdtp%3Dlt%26fcf%3D00BE0000003Suuk&amp;ent=Case&amp;from=&amp;isdtp=lt" id="actionForm" method="POST" name="actionForm" onsubmit="return verifyChecked(actionForm, 'ids', 'Please select at least one row')" target="mainFrame">
            <input type="hidden" name="isdtp" id="isdtp" value="mn">
            <input type="hidden" name="retURL" id="retURL" value="/500?isdtp=lt&amp;fcf=00BE0000003Suuk">
        <div class="pbHeader">
            <div class="listHeader">...</div>
        </div>
        <div class="pbBody">
            <table class="list" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="headerRow">...</tr>
                    <!-- ListRow -->
                    <tr class="dataRow even first bRowHilight" id="row_500E000000B8LgY" onblur="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onfocus="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onmouseout="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onmouseover="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}">...</tr>
                    <!-- ListRow -->
                    <tr class="dataRow odd" id="row_500E000000B77FP" onblur="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onfocus="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onmouseout="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onmouseover="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}">...</tr>
                    <!-- ListRow -->
                    <tr class="dataRow even" id="row_500E000000B8NHk" onblur="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onfocus="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onmouseout="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onmouseover="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}">...</tr>
                    <!-- ListRow -->
                    <tr class="dataRow odd last" id="row_500E000000B7TIG" onblur="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onfocus="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onmouseout="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onmouseover="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}">...</tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here, when I type #('.className') in the console I get "null" out.

However, when I type in, for example,

```
$('.bodyDiv.brdPalette.brandPrimaryBrd')
```

I get out the element:

```
<div class="bodyDiv brdPalette brandPrimaryBrd">...</div>
```

(This div is not included in the source above, but it is one of the first (least indented) divs on the page.

I have also tried `getElementsByClassName(".dataRow.odd")` and `getElementsByClassName(".dataRow odd")` but neither of these work.

Is there any reason that the `$('.myClass')` selector should not work?

My goal is to write a script that will run and tell me how many rows exist in the table. I have this so far:

```
    // ==UserScript==
    // @name       SalesForce JS to AutoRefresh
    // @version    0.1
    // @match      https://na9.salesforce.com/ui/desktop/DesktopPage
    // @copyright  2012+, You
    // ==/UserScript==

    var time = new Date().getTime();

    var numCases = $('.dataRow.odd').length + $('.dataRow.even').length;

    function refresh() 
    {
        console.log("Inside Function");
        if(new Date().getTime() - time >= 10000) 
        {
               time = new Date().getTime();
               freshImage.click();
               console.log("Refreshed");
               console.log("num Cases = " + numCases);
               if($('.dataRow.odd').length + $('.dataRow.even').length > numCases)
               {
                   while(numCases-- > $('.dataRow.odd').length + $('.dataRow.even').length)
                       beep(100,0);
                }
         }
         setTimeout(refresh, 1000);
    }

    var beep = (function () { .... /*beeps*/})();

    setTimeout(refresh, 1000);
```

I think everything is working, except that
    $('.dataRow.odd').length + $('.dataRow.even').length
will not work (because $('dataRow.odd') returns null)

Thanks for the responses so far. Sorry if my answer wasn't clear before--still pretty new to this.

Thanks!

Comment: you mean the classes dataRow and odd?

Comment: And what does the element look like, you're sure you're not just looking for `$('.dataRow .odd')`

Comment: In vanilla-js, use `document.querySelectorAll(".dataRow.odd")` or `document.getElementsByClassName("dataRow odd")`. In jQuery, use `$('.dataRow.odd')`

Comment: `$('.dataRow.odd')` should do what you want. Can you elaborate on this: "For some of the parent classes, this method seems to work, and I can get the element. As soon as I get into an ancestor it will not work."

Comment: Wait, do you have one or two classes? You mention the "class" dataRow odd but based on the rules for classes, you have two classes

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using the `:nth-child(odd)` pseudo selector?

Comment: @Oriol - Really, `document.getElementsByClassName("dataRow odd")` works for you ?

Comment: @Oriol: It should be `document.getElementsByClassName("dataRow", "odd")`

Comment: @cookiemonster - Actually, according to MDN it should be a list of classnames delimited by space, but both seem to work in latest Chrome? I didn't think you could reference multiple classes, but you can.

Comment: @cookiemonster - It should be `document.getElementsByClassName("dataRow odd")`. That is the correct syntax; `getElementsByClassName` only has one parameter. [(MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName)

Comment: @adeneo: You're right. I thought it was specified as a variadic function. I rarely use it since I typically do `qSA`. However the multiple args works for me in Firefox. I wonder if this is a case of spec vs historical implementations.

Comment: Most annoying part of this question is that most of it talks about multiple classes, but then the last part asks *"Is there any reason that the `$('.myClass')` selector should not work?"* I don't know what he's actually asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to return an array of all items belonging to the class `dataRow odd`.

Please notice that because *class* is a whitespace-delimited token list, `dataRow odd` is actually *two classes*, one `dataRow` and the other `odd`.

Combine this knowledge back with *CSS Selectors* and you'll realise the easiest way to select a single *Element* with both of these classes is to use

```
.dataRow.odd
```

which will match

```
<span class="dataRow odd"></span>
<span class="odd dataRow"></span>
<span class="foo odd bar dataRow baz"></span>
```

Notice also that [`node.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) doesn't take a *Selector*, but instead a *String* which is a whitespace-delimited class token list. If you wish to use a selector in vanilla *JavaScript* then the methods you'd be looking for are [`node.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) or [`node.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll)

Further, the result of these methods will be the first matching *Element (or null)* and a *NodeList (or HTMLCollection)*, respectively. To convert a *NodeList* into an *Array*, you can perform the following

```
var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodeList);
```

Comment: Yet the question states the OP has tried `$('.dataRow.odd')`

Comment: And following that statement it says `As soon as I get into an ancestor it will not work`

Comment: Hi @PaulS., I've tried both of these, but I'm still getting out "null" when I type them into the console. Is there a reason I might have to use an inner node instead of document.querySelectorAll("dataRow odd")?

Comment: I marked this as the answer, even though it didn't work for me, because it *should* have worked with the information I provided. The problem was that the class was referenced inside of an iframe. In order to get the $('.className') to work, I had to jquerify the webpage, and then get the iframe with $("#iframeID"), use the .contents() method to get the stuff inside the iframe, and then find(".dataRow") to get the elements I was looking for.

Thanks everyone for the answers. Sorry I didn't provide enough details, I just wasn't sure where to add information, or that an iframe was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Create an array (elements in example). Loop through each element with the class name and push to elements array.

```
var elements = [];

$('.dataRow.odd').each(function(){
     elements.push($(this));
}):
```

Your missing the " . " on $('.dataRow odd') in your example code. 
Also the difference between selecting child elements and muti-class elements.

Child

```
$('.dataRow .odd'); (space include here)

<div class="dataRow">
   <div class="odd"></div>
</div>
```

Muti-class

```
$('.dataRow.odd'); (no space)

<div class="dataRow odd">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @DonaldPowell. Thanks very much for your answer. I'm still having difficulty though, not because the function isn't working, I think, but because it's not returning any objects belonging to the class. Do you think there's a reason $('dataRow.odd') might not be finding my elements?

Comment: Comment above shows $('dataRow.odd'). I believe you want $('.dataRow.odd'). You want an period(".") before any class name and an hash/pound ("#") before id names. Try $('.dataRow.odd').

Comment: Thanks @DonaldPowell, but still no luck :/